# sliding page inside div onclick instead of on load

Tags: jquery, html

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slideContent").animate({
        marginLeft: $(".slideContent").css('margin-left') == '903px' ?
            '0px' : '0px'
    }, function () {
        // Animation complete.
        $(".contentWrapper").css('z-index', '1');
    });
```

### HTML

```
<div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="content slideContent homeContent">
        <div class="content-text slideContentWrapper">    
        </div>
    </div>               
</div>
```

Right Now `onload` I did this. I do not want to reload page. I just want slide should happen on click.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id").click(function(){
    $(".slideContent").animate({        
      marginLeft : $(".slideContent").css('margin-left') == '903px' ? '0px' : '0px'                      
    }, function() {
      // Animation complete.
      $(".contentWrapper").css('z-index','1');
  });
});
```

Comment: this is not working for me. I tried this sliding page itself not come if I add click code. Any other solution please

Comment: your code missing some brackets. Just wrap your working code inside `$("#id").click(function(){ // your working code here});` change `id` to your id were you are clicking.